# How to capture a complete view of an Activity Screen in Android

Tags: android

*I am using a scroll View in my activity.I want to share the whole activity screen but not able to do that.Am able to share the visible part of the screen but not the full screen of the activity.Is it possible to take the screenshot of the full activity.I have tried like this but its sharing only the visible part of the activity*.Plz help me out of this.Thank You

```
   ShareImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             //View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView();

              View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content); 

             v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
             myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();
             saveBitmap(myBitmap);


        }

    });
```

*Saving the Screenshot taken ::*

```
  public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator + "Pictures/screencapture.png";
     File imagePath = new File(filePath);
     FileOutputStream fos;
     try {
     fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();
     share(filePath);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     Log.e("exception1", e.getMessage(), e);
     } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("exception2", e.getMessage(), e);
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:

     public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

}

Comment: Am confused with the height and width which is used in the method.depending upon the screen size of the screen we need to pass the height and width of the screen.@Anantham

Comment: view.getWidth() and view.getHeight  @Gauravsingh

Comment: its working but still its taking the snapshot of the visible area not the whole activity screen shot.Any other way to capture the whole screen @Anantham